# Any Java Iterators that close automatically (like C#)?

Tags: c#, java, iterator, idisposable

I'm from a C# background where the iterators implement [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface. Are there any iterators in Java that implement a similar interface that makes them close automatically?

Comment: Which iterators implement `IDisposable`?  Can you give an example?

Comment: @DanPuzey - IEnumerator<T> implements IDisposable

Comment: How lame on behalf of java is this!

Comment: [I had wished for Java Streams to be more like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34753078/521799). Unfortunately, they aren't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java's Iterator is just an abstraction for iterating over some collection of objects. If the underlying data structure needs some clean-up after iteration (e.g. closing a file), then you need to keep a reference to that underlying object so you can do whatever must be done to "dispose" of it.

Answer (score 4):

In Java 7, you could create your own iterator (or a decorator for one) which also happens to implement AutoCloseable.  You could then use it in a try block:

```
try ( Iterator<MyObject> it = new MyAutoCloseableIterator(list) ) {
    while (it.hasNext()) {
       MyObject obj = it.next();
    }
}
```

At the end of the try block, if the Iterator implements AutoCloseable interface, the ".close()" method will automagically be called on it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

I don't believe however that any of the built in iterators (which typically are inner classes to the collections, and thus not publicly available) implement this interface.

Another option would be to (again) code your own iterator, and close resources when the ".hasNext()" method return false.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) is an interface itself. And it doesn't have any `close()` method.

Answer (score 1):

This is the API offered by an [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

> Method Summary
>
> boolean  hasNext()
>             Returns true if the iteration has more elements.    E   next()
>             Returns the next element in the iteration.    void  remove()
>             Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by the iterator (optional operation).

It was meant to replace `Enumeration` in the Java collections framework and is being used to iterate over a collection. It is based on the `Iterator` design pattern.
It's purpose is exactly what is offered. I.e. iteration. Has nothing to do with `close` etc.
If a class that implements the iterator interface e.g. [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) offers a `close` this is part of the `Scanner` API. Unrelated to the iterator aspect/interface