# Register a Stream "completion" hook

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Using the Java 8 `Stream` API, I would like to register a "completion hook", along the lines of:

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("a", "b", "c");

// additional filters / mappings that I don't control
stream.onComplete((Completion c) -> {
    // This is what I'd like to do:
    closeResources();

    // This might also be useful:
    Optional<Throwable> exception = c.exception();
    exception.ifPresent(e -> throw new ExceptionWrapper(e));
});
```

The reason why I want to do that is because I want to wrap a resource in a `Stream` for API clients to consume, and I want that `Stream` to clean up the resource automatically once it is consumed. If that were possible, then the client could call:

```
Collected collectedInOneGo =
Utility.something()
       .niceLookingSQLDSL()
       .moreDSLFeatures()
       .stream()
       .filter(a -> true)
       .map(c -> c)
       .collect(collector);
```

Rather than what's needed currently:

```
try (Stream<X> meh = Utility.something()
                            .niceLookingSQLDSL()
                            .moreDSLFeatures()
                            .stream()) {

    Collected collectedWithUglySyntacticDissonance =
    meh.filter(a -> true)
       .map(c -> c)
       .collect(collector);
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to get into the `java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline`'s various methods, such as:

```
@Override
final void forEachWithCancel(Spliterator<P_OUT> spliterator, Sink<P_OUT> sink) {
    try {

        // Existing loop
        do { } while (!sink.cancellationRequested() && spliterator.tryAdvance(sink));
    }

    // These would be nice:
    catch (Throwable t) {
        completion.onFailure(t);
    }
    finally {
        completion.onSuccess();
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this with existing JDK 8 API?

Comment: Note that the JDK itself included some streams that involve resources that need to be closed, and the JDK stuck with recommending explicit try-with-resources behavior for those streams.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Any solution intercepting the terminal operations except `flatMap`-based solution (as proposed by @Holger) would be fragile to the following code:

```
Stream<String> stream = getAutoCloseableStream();
if(stream.iterator().hasNext()) {
    // do something if stream is non-empty
}
```

Such usage is absolutely legal by the specification. Do not forget that `iterator()` and `spliterator()` are terminal stream operations, but after their execution you still need an access to the stream source. Also it's perfectly valid to abandon the `Iterator` or `Spliterator` in any state, so you just cannot know whether it will be used further or not.

You may consider advicing users not to use `iterator()` and `spliterator()`, but what about this code?

```
Stream<String> stream = getAutoCloseableStream();
Stream.concat(stream, Stream.of("xyz")).findFirst();
```

This internally uses `spliterator().tryAdvance()` for the first stream, then abandons it (though closes if the resulting stream `close()` is called explicitly). You will need to ask your users not to use `Stream.concat` as well. And as far as I know internally in your library you are using `iterator()`/`spliterator()` pretty often, so you will need to revisit all these places for possible problems. And, of course there are plenty of other libraries which also use `iterator()`/`spliterator()` and may short-circuit after that: all of them would become incompatible with your feature.

Why `flatMap`-based solution works here? Because upon the first call of the `hasNext()` or `tryAdvance()` it dumps the **entire** stream content into the intermediate buffer and closes the original stream source. So depending on the stream size you may waste much intermediate memory or even have `OutOfMemoryError`.

You may also consider keeping the `PhantomReference`s to the `Stream` objects and monitoring the `ReferenceQueue`. In this case the completion will be triggered by garbage collector (which also has some drawbacks).

In conclusion my advice is to stay with try-with-resources.

Comment: A `flatMap` doesn’t have to be eager to implement this behavior, the implementation knows when it is switching from one substream to the next one, thus, can close the old one at this point and have at most one pending substream. And having an internal cleanup action in the `Stream` implementation is nothing fancy. The reason why `flatMap` makes such a guaranty is that it is otherwise impossible for the code supplying the substream to ensure a proper cleanup (a problem similar to the OP’s question).

Comment: @Holger, yes it does not have to be. I'm describing the current implementation. Though probably it's too late to change this as some people might already rely on current behavior. What if the outer stream does not hold the resource to close, but inner streams hold? Currently you don't have to use try-with-resources. If the implementation changes, you may have a resource leak.

Comment: I wasn’t suggesting to add the requirement to close the outer stream, that’s indeed too late, just to make `flatMap` as lazy as it should be, claiming that this is possible for most terminal actions. However, if a stream user calls `iterator()` or `spliterator()`, there’s indeed no other choice than falling back to eager behavior to be compatible.

Comment: Excellent point about concat. I give up. Lazy resource allocation inside of Stream is but wishful thinking. To me, this shows that stream should perhaps simply not be AutoClosable at all...

Answer (score 13):

The simplest solution is to wrap a stream in another stream and flatmap it to itself:

```
// example stream
Stream<String> original=Stream.of("bla").onClose(()->System.out.println("close action"));

// this is the trick
Stream<String> autoClosed=Stream.of(original).flatMap(Function.identity());

//example op
int sum=autoClosed.mapToInt(String::length).sum();
System.out.println(sum);
```

The reason why it works lies in the [`flatMap` operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

> Each mapped stream is closed after its contents have been placed into this stream.

But [the current implementation isn’t as lazy as it should be when using `flatMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29229373/2711488). This has been fixed in Java 10.

---

My recommendation is to stay with the `try(…)` standard solution and document when a returned stream needs to be closed. After all, a stream that closes the resource after the terminal operation isn’t safe as there is no guaranty that the client will actually invoke a terminal operation. Changing its mind and abandon a stream instead, is a valid use, whereas not calling the `close()` method, when the documentation specifies that it is required, is not.

Comment: Very interesting discovery! "*as there is no guaranty that the client will actually invoke a terminal operation*" - Indeed, but the opening of the resource could be delayed until the terminal operation is invoked.

Comment: Right, since practical use cases will go through `StreamSupport` anyway, using the lazy factory methods is an option.

Answer (score 7):

Java 8 already has a precedent for how streams that need to be closed operate.  In their [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), it mentions:

> Streams have a BaseStream.close() method and implement AutoCloseable, but nearly all stream instances do not actually need to be closed after use. Generally, only streams whose source is an IO channel (such as those returned by Files.lines(Path, Charset)) will require closing. Most streams are backed by collections, arrays, or generating functions, which require no special resource management. (If a stream does require closing, it can be declared as a resource in a try-with-resources statement.)

So Java 8's recommendation is to open those streams in a try-with-resources.  And once you do that, `Stream` *also* provides a way for you to add a close hook, almost exactly as you've described: [`onClose(Runnable)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#onClose-java.lang.Runnable-), which accepts a lambda telling it what to do and returns a `Stream` that will also do that operation when it is closed.

That's the way the API design and documentation suggests to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: The close hook is invoked when someone explicitly closes the stream. I'm already using that to implement the current "ugly" behaviour. Yes, that's what the Javadoc suggests, but perhaps, there's a trick that doesn't violate any contract, that can enhance the current API.

Comment: @LukasEder Pretty much what I'm saying is that the JDK set a precedent that that's the way to do it, and you should really stick with that.  They're a lot smarter than...well, me, frankly.

Comment: I don't agree. 1) history has shown a lot of caveats even in the JDK. Some things have just gone unnoticed, or are not (yet) supported. And no specification was ever non-ambiguous or complete. 2) [Holger's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34753512/521799) shows that with existing API, the semantics I'm after *can* be (partially) implemented, at least the completion hook (not the failure hook). 3) The particular Javadoc you've linked is a bit vague. See the wording *"Generally"*, or *"can be closed"* (rather than *"must be"*) which opens a lot of grounds for interpretation.

Comment: 4) The [`AutoCloseable` contract was changed specifically](http://blog.jooq.org/2015/12/02/a-subtle-autocloseable-contract-change-between-java-7-and-java-8/) to accommodate `Stream`, which was in my opinion not the very best move compared to alternatives (e.g. introducing a new super type `OptionallyAutoCloseable`), so these specs are not set in stone, unalterable, or unquestionable.

Comment: I can understand that opinion, but the JDK seems to have pretty deliberately decided on this behavior -- they clearly considered this sort of case and this was the API they came up with -- and the API seems pretty designed for this approach.  I don't think it's ambiguous how the JDK wanted these use cases to be dealt with.

What you write is up to you.  I just don't think there's good enough justification here to ignore the approach the JDK seems to have decided was the Right Way to deal with this use case.

Comment: Fair enough. Let's hope some EG member will show up on this Stack Overflow question...

Comment: @LukasEder Listen to Louis; he has it right.  The issue you are raising did not arise from an "unnoticed" situation; in fact, it was extensively discussed.  The rule is simple: he who acquires the resource, releases the resource.  Expecting the stream to close the resources from whence it came when its done is (a) unreliable and (b) wrong.  If you want it to be closed, acquire it in a TWR block.

Comment: @LukasEder, as for AutoCloseable, even in Java-7 there are bunch of classes which are unnecessary to close (like `ByteArrayOutputStream` or `StringReader`). It's explicitly specified in their documentation (e.g. "Closing a `ByteArrayOutputStream` has no effect"). So it's not an API change, but a clarification.

Comment: @BrianGoetz thanks, Brian. Ultimately, Tagir's answer convinced me. I think the problem is that Stream perhaps shouldn't be AutoClosable, or iterator() should return an AutoClosableIterator, and Spliterator should also extend AutoClosable

Comment: @LukasEder Or maybe, there's just not a problem, there's just a choice of "how much friction are we willing to tolerate in exchange for extending the use of this abstraction outside its sweet spot."  You'd be unhappy if we said "streams can't be closed at all, so IO-based streams lose."  But extending an idiom beyond its sweet spot involves compromise.  (There is of course room to differ on how far to extend and how to compromise, but ultimately I think the real problem is the (implicit) assumption that a mistake must have been made.)

Answer (score 3):

The solution I've come up with looks like this:

```
class AutoClosingStream<T> implements Stream<T> {

    AutoClosingStream(Stream<T> delegate, Consumer<Optional<Throwable>> onComplete) {}

    // Pipeline ops delegate the op to the real stream and wrap that again
    @Override
    public Stream<T> limit(long maxSize) {
        return new AutoClosingStream(delegate.limit(maxSize), onComplete);
    }

    // Terminal ops intercept the result and call the onComplete logic
    @Override
    public void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        terminalOp(() -> delegate.forEach(action));
    }

    private void terminalOp(Runnable runnable) {
        terminalOp(() -> { runnable.run(); return null; });
    }

    private <R> R terminalOp(Supplier<R> supplier) {
        R result = null;

        try {
            result = supplier.get();
            onComplete.accept(Optional.empty());
        }
        catch (Throwable e) {
            onComplete.accept(Optional.of(e));
            Utils.sneakyThrow(e);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

This is only a simplified sketch to illustrate the idea. The real solution would also support the primitive `IntStream`, `LongStream`, and `DoubleStream`

Comment: So you have to override/implement all >30 methods of the `Stream` interface (four times) and it will break as soon as a client uses one of the upcoming Java 9 `default` methods. Doesn’t sound like a solution to me.

Comment: @Holger: I don't worry about implementing 4x30 methods. I'm aware of the JDK 9 restriction. But those new methods won't be big surprises. Currently, there are [3 new methods](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), which I can already implement today, and delegate using reflection (or implement myself). I do agree, though, that this aspect of possible backwards-incompatibility with future JDK versions is a bit of a drawback.

Comment: Note that the sneaky throw is completely unnecessary here. You can simply use `catch(Throwable e) { /*some action*/ throw e; }`

Comment: Hint ~ [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

Comment: @Holger: Very nice, I wasn't aware of this subtle bit of flow-sensitive typing

Comment: @EddieB: I'm aware of the `CompletableFuture` API and something along the lines of its methods in `Stream` would be great. How does it help here, though?

Comment: @LukasEder Sorry... a bit confused by the title... 'completion hook'

Comment: @Lukas Eder: the exception handling improvements were introduced in Java 7, together with the `try(…)` statement, multi-catch, etc. That’s why the concept of a variable being “effectively final” is not new to Java 8, it’s already required for this Java 7 construct.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these complete implementations of AutoClosingReferenceStream, AutoClosingIntStream, AutoClosingLongStream and AutoClosingDoubleStream   at the open-source project Speedment   https://github.com/speedment/speedment/tree/master/src/main/java/com/speedment/internal/core/stream/autoclose

The solution is similar to the one mentioned by @LukasEder