# Do I risk a JDBC connection leak when streaming JOOQ results outside a try-with-resources block?

Tags: java-8, java-stream, jooq, autocloseable

I have a JOOQ query where I want to avoid materializing all Records at the same time. (However, I am fine with jointly materializing all bean objects created from them.)

I have the following simple method to load the data:

```
public List<CustomerInfo> getCustomers() {
    return dslContext
                .selectFrom(CUSTOMER)
                // <-- note the missing .fetch()
                .stream()
                .map(CustomerInfo::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Can this lead to a JDBC connection leak in any circumstances? (e.g. an Exception in `CustomerInfo::new`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've tried my luck finding a way to register a reliable stream "completion" hook that fires on complete stream consumption or on any exception, but that's not possible, unfortunately: [Register a Stream "completion" hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753078/register-a-stream-completion-hook)

So, indeed, the code you have shown is not correct. The correct way to operate with "lazy" streams (or [`Cursor`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Cursor.html)) is to use the try-with-resources statement. The following two are equivalent:

```
// Using a Stream
try (Stream<CustomerRecord> stream = dslContext.selectFrom(CUSTOMER).stream()) {
    return stream.map(CustomerInfo::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

// Using a Cursor
try (Cursor<CustomerRecord> cursor = dslContext.selectFrom(CUSTOMER).fetchLazy()) {
    return cursor.stream().map(CustomerInfo::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Notice also the [`ResultQuery.stream()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#stream--) javadoc:

> This is essentially the same as fetchLazy() but instead of returning a Cursor, a Java 8 Stream is returned. Clients should ensure the Stream is properly closed, e.g. in a try-with-resources statement