# Jooq consumes all available DB connections from Hikari CP

Tags: java, mysql, jooq, hikaricp

I'm writing a MySQL based app using Jooq and Hikari:

```java
final HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
config.setMinimumIdle(10);
config.setMaximumPoolSize(100);
config.setConnectionTimeout(10000);
config.setMinimumIdle(10);
config.setJdbcUrl(AppConfig2.getMySqlUrl());
config.setUsername(AppConfig2.getMySqlUser());
config.setPassword(AppConfig2.getMySqlPassword());
final HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
dslContext = DSL.using(dataSource, SQLDialect.MYSQL, settings);
```

Then I use this dslContext in my code to read data from the database. Problem is, after one or two calls, all 100 connections are consumed which is unexpected.

After a few initial DB calls, I get `HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 10007ms.` error and with Hikari stats it telle me:

```
HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=100, active=100, idle=0, waiting=0)
HikariPool-1 - After cleanup  stats (total=100, active=100, idle=0, waiting=0)
```

To me it seems like Jooq is greedily creating and keeping DB connections open and does not return them to the connection pool.

The commands in my code are simple `fetchOne`s like:

```java
var twitterUser = dslContext.fetchOne(TWITTER_USER, TWITTER_USER.ID.eq(currentUserId));
var inboxUser = dslContext.fetchOne(INBOX_USER, INBOX_USER.TWITTER_USER_ID.eq(currentUserId));
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, I was running a statement without a call to `fetch` and Jooq does not issue any warnings about that. That statement was executed for lots of data items, which caused a fresh connection acquisition on each item.

```java
return dslContext.selectFrom(TWITTER_DIRECT_MESSAGE)
            .where(
                TWITTER_DIRECT_MESSAGE.SENDER_ID.eq(senderId)
                    .and(TWITTER_DIRECT_MESSAGE.RECIPIENT_ID.eq(recipientId))
            ).orderBy(TWITTER_DIRECT_MESSAGE.CREATED_AT.desc())
            .limit(1)
            .fetch() //this was missing!!!
            .stream()
            .map(TwitterDirectMessageRecord::getCreatedAt)
            .findFirst();
```

Answer (score 2):

The jOOQ manual shows examples on [how to correctly stream results with jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/lazy-fetching-with-streams/). The [`ResultQuery::stream` method](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#stream()) mentions it too. The method returns a *resourceful* stream, which you have to close yourself:

```java
try (Stream<R> stream = query.stream()) {
    // Do things with stream
}
```

There is no other way. See also this rejected feature request about returning auto-closing streams: [#4932](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4932), which was rejected because of various reasons listed here: [Register a Stream "completion" hook](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34753078/521799)

If you don't really need resourceful (lazy) streams, then [you already found the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73179356/521799): call `fetch()` to eagerly fetch all data into memory first, and stream the resulting list.

Comment: It also happens when we fail to call execute() for insert statements.

Comment: @AvinashJeeva: That doesn't sound legitimate. jOOQ won't acquire any resources in those cases, so this must be masking some other error. Best ask a new question.